# How to find the angle between diagonals of a quadrilateral when all its angles is known?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, quadrilateral

I need to find the red angles: $\angle(AOB)$, $\angle(BOC)$, $\angle(COD)$, $\angle(AOD)$.

The green angles are known: $\angle(ABC)$, $\angle(BCD)$, $\angle(CDA)$, $\angle(DAB)$.

Is there any general approach to find the red angles? I assume it should be.

[image]

If it's impossible, then I'm ready to consider the general approach for the other more detailed case, when I know a little more angles:
$$
\angle(ABC), \angle(BCD), \angle(CDA), \angle(DAB), \angle(OAD), \angle(OAB), \angle(OCB), \angle(OCD)
$$

The picture is pretty same:

[image]

If it's still not enough, I can add the limitation to convex quadrilaterals and maybe some other restrictions.

The preferable result is a general formula for the angles without any trigonometry manipulations.

Comment: You can't find this angle from the angles at $A, B, C, D$, because those angles don't entirely determine the shape of the quadrilateral. For example, you could take a parallelogram and then stretch it to make it really long, but keeping the sides parallel to those of the original parallelogram. After enough stretching, the angle between the diagonals would become close to zero, but the angles at the vertices wouldn't have changed. (Obviously, though, if you know one of the angles at $O$, it is very easy to find the other angles at $O$.)

Comment: And what about the second case, when I know OAD, OBA, OCD and OCB? That angles will change in your example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you mean you know all four angles at the vertices and also $OAD$? That would be enough to determine the shape of $ABCD$.

Comment: Yes, it's the second case. Moreover, I know all four angles and $OAD$, $OBA$, $OCD$, $OCB$.

Comment: Who does downvote the question? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As anonymous points out, your problem cannot be solved.  Consider this example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the illustration, but as I pointed out in the comments I have *two* cases. I said in advance that one of the cases can be unsolvable. Moreover, if all two cases are unsolvable I can add additional limitations, but before I should know that they are unsolvable.